# Android GreenRobot's EventBus 'register' method crashes my application

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

Using the described method causes my application to crash without any exception whatsoever. What can make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that my "onEvent" method was not PUBLIC. It has to be public - it surprises me it is stated ordinarily within its documentation.

Comment: Thanks! this was my exact issue